# Animate LongListSelector item on Hold Event

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to animate a longlistselectoritem when I hold it. I was checking for the event hold to start the animation from a storyboard I have in the AppResources, however, FrameworkElement doesn't have the BeginStoryboard in Windows Phone.

I'm just trying to change the color and do a transform on the item being held.

Comment: When developing for Windows phone I used the Blend SDK:s and created my own "ControlStoryboardAction", inheriting from `TriggerAction<UIElement>`. If you don't find an alternative, perhaps you can look at that.. I don't know if it works for WP8 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for hours I gave up and made a UserControl out of the template and in there I was able to control the VisualStates and animate my control. Not a very clean solution, but it works very well, with a little work the control can be made to work with any template.